# Excel conditional formatting rules based on how often a value occures

Tags: excel

in the excel book, the columns "SZ" to "Z6" are to be formated.

[image: Cells to be formated]

The goal is to format the cells with a color scale not based on the row value, but based on how often the value occurs. I have created a second table, the value in which is the frequency of the value in the first table. Columns "SZ Formating" to "Z6 Formating" represent how often the Value in the first table occure.

[image: The formated Table]

Is there a way to have the values of the first table and the color scale formatting of the second?

Comment: color scale formatting in Excel are based on the **values** of the cells. You can compare those values to a formula but cannot force excel to make a formula as source data to compare against other data and then apply CF rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force it doin your own scale but this heavyly overcharges thr worksheet.

I created 5 Conditional formatting rules based on the same conditions just to check if the number of appearances of each value matchs the max, the min or the middle of appeareances:

[image]

The five CF rules:
[image]

The formulas of each rule:

```
=COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;C5)=MAX(COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;$C$5:$I$31))
=COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;C5)>=0,75*MAX(COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;$C$5:$I$31))
=COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;C5)>=0,50*MAX(COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;$C$5:$I$31))
=COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;C5)>=0,25*MAX(COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;$C$5:$I$31))
=COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;C5)=MIN(COUNTIF($C$5:$I$31;$C$5:$I$31))
```

You can see in the image that:

1. Cells with number 2 are highlited in dark green because 2 is the value with **most** occurrences.
2. Cells with number 5 are highlited in red because 14 is the value with **least** occurrences.
3. Rest of cells are based on occurendes % (over 75%, over 50% or over 25%).

Anyways, as I said, this overcharges worksheet **overwhelming** so I won't recommend it. I developed this just for fun because I was not sure if this was possible.